# Creating a Singleton in a NDK static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, singleton, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm trying to creating a singleton for 2 different libraries in android ndk.

Imagine that I have:

- lib1 (static)
- lib2 (shared)
- lib3 (shared)

`lib1` is always defined as LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES of `lib2` and `lib3`

But when I set the value of the singleton on lib2, this value remains NULL on lib3.

How can I build a singleton with this architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is common and admits no good solution, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911994/sharing-a-global-static-variable-between-a-process-and-dll) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616148/sharing-memory-between-modules). The shared libraries have separate copies of linked-in static libraries, both code and data. The static library instances in different SO's just don't interact, and for many good reasons, too.

What you need is a chunk of memory that is accessible to both. You can move the singleton up to the Java level (it's under Android after all). You can have a temporary file with a well known name. C-level TLS might help, too.

Android's shared memory facility (`ashmem`) will be of no use, as it does not provide named blocks.